# PHP in page calculations

Tags: php, forms, validation

Currently I am working on a reservations website, I have implemented select boxes and radio buttons to enable the user to select their party size and if they want VIP seating. I have also implemented a price factor based off of these two selections.

I have enabled php to perform the calculations once the submit button is pressed by the user, however I would much prefer for these calculations to be performed automatically on screen once the user makes a selection.

Here is the html code for the party size selection:

```
<select name="party" value="<?php echo $party;?>">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="5") echo "selected";?> value="5">1 Person (£5)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="10") echo "selected";?> value="10">2 People (£10)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="15") echo "selected";?> value="15">3 People (£15)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="20") echo "selected";?> value="20">4 People (£20)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="25") echo "selected";?> value="25">5 People (£25)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="30") echo "selected";?> value="30">6 People (£30)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="35") echo "selected";?> value="35">7 People (£35)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="40") echo "selected";?> value="40">8 People (£40)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="45") echo "selected";?> value="45">9 People (£45)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="50") echo "selected";?> value="50">10+ People (£50)</option>
</select>
<span id="partySize" class="error"><?php echo $partyErr;?></span>
```

Here is the html code for the VIP selection:

```
<strong> VIP area* : </strong> <br><br>
Yes (+£5) <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="5") echo "checked";?> value="5">
<br><span id="vip" class="error"><?php echo $vipErr;?></span><br>
No <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="0") echo "checked";?> value="0">
```

Here is the php I am currently using:

```
$party = (int)$_POST['party'];
$vip = (int)$_POST['vip'];
$cost = $party + $vip;
...
<strong>Total booking cost based on party size & VIP selection: £<?php echo $cost; ?></strong>
```

If anyone knows how I might achieve this, please help! Thank you

Comment: "on screen"? Then you'll have to use javascript, and PHP won't be involved in any way for that portion. PHP runs on a server, and only in response to http requests. If you want your form to adjust itself and print messages as a user interacts with it, then you can't use PHP - you'll have to use javascript.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for your feedback. Would you know how this might be possible in javascript, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually achieved with AJAX, to resume this for you, AJAX sends data to server and recieve responses from server without refreshing page. You need to learn about it to achiev this. Take look at some of this links

[xmlHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

[jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript.Use eval function in the option